# How we can update droptree value of an item using PowerShell query

Tags: powershell-extensions

Does anyone know how to Update `droptree` field values through Powershell?

We have the bulk of items, which one of the field values as `__Workflow state` under workflow section[while we can see enable standard template].
we need to update as a state(`__Workflow state`) as empty for all the items. could you please suggest how we can write a query in Powershell.

```
$sourcepath="master:/sitecore/content/TestFolder";
$items= Get-ChildItem -path $sourcepath -Recurse

function Update-Item{

foreach($item in $items)
{
    if($item.TemplateId -eq "{292FD0AD-CE76-4867-B43B-A58FC8F36530}")       
    {
        Write-host  "Updating Item Name and AGE:" $item.ID "";
        $rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.ReferenceField]$item.Fields["__Workflow state"]
        $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
        
        $item.Editing.EndEdit()
    }   
}

$items = Update-Item
Close-Window
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make a field empty you can do it using:

```
 $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
 $item["__Workflow state"]=""
 $item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Comment: Yeah its working. thanks. due to cache issue, its not reflected in browser. After checking incognito window. its showing perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Reset-ItemField` command to reset the workflow state to the default state. This is [covered in Example 4](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/reset-itemfield#example-4) in the SPE book.

```
Reset-ItemField -Item $item -Name "__Workflow State" -IncludeStandardFields
```